# Forcing 32-bit architecture via configure

Tags: c++, linux, configure

What is the best way to force a configure script to build a 32-bit code?

I have a 64-bit machine, and trying to build a 32-bit code.
Tried setting the --build type with several options, but this just doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add `-m32` to the `CFLAGS`.

Comment: How exactly do you do this?  I tried `CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 ./configure` and still got a 64-bit result.

Comment: how is this different than arch -i386?